# Getting "SyntaxError: EOL while scanning string literal' when using flask on creating contacts form

Tags: python, flask

I am using flask to create a contacts form. I want to send emails by using this contact form.

I keep getting this error in my terminal whenever I run python routes.py

```
File "routes.py", line 25
    msg = Message(form.subject.data, sender='contact@example.com<script type="text/javascript">

SyntaxError: EOL while scanning string literal
```

Here is my **routes.py** file.

```
@app.route('/contact', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def contact():
  form = ContactForm()

  if request.method == 'POST':
    if form.validate() == False:
      flash('All fields are required.')
      return render_template('contact.html', form=form)
    else:
      msg = Message(form.subject.data, sender='contact@example.com<script type="text/javascript">
/* <![CDATA[ */
(function(){try{var s,a,i,j,r,c,l,b=document.getElementsByTagName("script");l=b[b.length-1].previousSibling;a=l.getAttribute('data-cfemail');if(a){s='';r=parseInt(a.substr(0,2),16);for(j=2;a.length-j;j+=2){c=parseInt(a.substr(j,2),16)^r;s+=String.fromCharCode(c);}s=document.createTextNode(s);l.parentNode.replaceChild(s,l);}}catch(e){}})();
/* ]]> */
</script>', recipients=['your_email@example.com<script type="text/javascript">
/* <![CDATA[ */
(function(){try{var s,a,i,j,r,c,l,b=document.getElementsByTagName("script");l=b[b.length-1].previousSibling;a=l.getAttribute('data-cfemail');if(a){s='';r=parseInt(a.substr(0,2),16);for(j=2;a.length-j;j+=2){c=parseInt(a.substr(j,2),16)^r;s+=String.fromCharCode(c);}s=document.createTextNode(s);l.parentNode.replaceChild(s,l);}}catch(e){}})();
/* ]]> */
</script>'])
      msg.body = """
      From: %s <%s>
      %s
      """ % (form.name.data, form.email.data, form.message.data)
      mail.send(msg)

      return 'Form posted.'

  elif request.method == 'GET':
    return render_template('contact.html', form=form)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use triple quotes for multiline strings and the closing quotes should come after the `]`:

```
msg = Message(form.subject.data, sender='''contact@example.com<script type="text/javascript">
/* <![CDATA[ */
(function(){try{var s,a,i,j,r,c,l,b=document.getElementsByTagName("script");l=b[b.length-1].previousSibling;a=l.getAttribute('data-cfemail');if(a){s='';r=parseInt(a.substr(0,2),16);for(j=2;a.length-j;j+=2){c=parseInt(a.substr(j,2),16)^r;s+=String.fromCharCode(c);}s=document.createTextNode(s);l.parentNode.replaceChild(s,l);}}catch(e){}})();
/* ]]> */
</script>', recipients=['your_email@example.com<script type="text/javascript">
/* <![CDATA[ */
(function(){try{var s,a,i,j,r,c,l,b=document.getElementsByTagName("script");l=b[b.length-1].previousSibling;a=l.getAttribute('data-cfemail');if(a){s='';r=parseInt(a.substr(0,2),16);for(j=2;a.length-j;j+=2){c=parseInt(a.substr(j,2),16)^r;s+=String.fromCharCode(c);}s=document.createTextNode(s);l.parentNode.replaceChild(s,l);}}catch(e){}})();
/* ]]> */
</script>]''')
```

Answer (score 2):

You can't create a multiline string with `'...'`. You have to use `''' ... '''` or `""" ... """`.

Try:

```
msg = Message(form.subject.data, sender="""contact@example.com<script type="text/javascript">
/* <![CDATA[ */
(function(){try{var s,a,i,j,r,c,l,b=document.getElementsByTagName("script");l=b[b.length-1].previousSibling;a=l.getAttribute('data-cfemail');if(a){s='';r=parseInt(a.substr(0,2),16);for(j=2;a.length-j;j+=2){c=parseInt(a.substr(j,2),16)^r;s+=String.fromCharCode(c);}s=document.createTextNode(s);l.parentNode.replaceChild(s,l);}}catch(e){}})();
/* ]]> */
</script>', recipients=['your_email@example.com<script type="text/javascript">
/* <![CDATA[ */
(function(){try{var s,a,i,j,r,c,l,b=document.getElementsByTagName("script");l=b[b.length-1].previousSibling;a=l.getAttribute('data-cfemail');if(a){s='';r=parseInt(a.substr(0,2),16);for(j=2;a.length-j;j+=2){c=parseInt(a.substr(j,2),16)^r;s+=String.fromCharCode(c);}s=document.createTextNode(s);l.parentNode.replaceChild(s,l);}}catch(e){}})();
/* ]]> */
</script>"""])
```